# How to set priority to tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I have 4 tables to perform indexing. My problem is,

> I want to get search results not by weight but by tables priority. I
>   mean table 1 matched results show first then for table 2 and so on.
>
> Currently, it is retrieving results by highest weight first.

Query

```
Select UUID_SHORT() AS sphinxid, info as keyword, 'column_name' as type from table 1 
UNION ALL 
Select UUID_SHORT() AS sphinxid,  info as keyword, 'column_name' as type from table 2 
UNION ALL 
Select UUID_SHORT() AS sphinxid,  info as keyword, 'column_name' as type from table 3 
UNION ALL 
Select UUID_SHORT() AS sphinxid,  info as keyword, 'column_name' as type from table 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if still using original SphinxAPI, there is a SetIndexWeights. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setindexweights
Although would have to split the data into separate actual indexes.

... there isnt an equivlent in SphinxQL as such. AFAIK

Probably simplest to add a new attribute to the index

```
sql_query =   \
Select ...,8 as multiplier from table1  \
UNION ALL  \
Select ...,4 as multiplier from table2  \
UNION ALL  \
...

sql_attr_uint = multiplier
```

Then when running queries, can use that factor

```
sphinxQL> SELECT id,WEIGHT()*multiplier AS w FROM index WHERE MATCH(..) ORDER BY w DESC;
```